# Trying to select all but the 1st TD'd in the last row in a table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table that contains totals at the end. I need to select all TD's in the last row except the 1st TD which says the word TOTAL.

This does not seem to work, any idea's?

```
$(".tableclass tbody tr:last(td:not(first-child))").css({'color':'#FF0000'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do it ..

```
$('.tableclass tbody tr:last td:not(:first-child)').css({'color':'#FF0000'});
```